# Simple table with csvsimple, with no headers

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I am not managing to make a simple table in csvsimple.

My data is like this:
value 1, 5.5
value 2, 3806.0
value 3, 601.0
value 4, 26.8
value 5, 150.0
value 6, 2.0
value 8, 75.0
value 9, 21

I have made the following code and I cannot figure out what is the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[tabular==|l|r|,
no head,
table head=\hline,
late after line=\\\hline
]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: 1. After the key `tabular`, there should be only one `=`.
2. `\csvreader` requires three regular arguments.
3. Try `\csvreader[tabular=|l|r|,no head,table head=\hline,late after line=\\\hline]{data.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}` (note the second and third argument).
4. [Read the fine manual](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

[**EDIT** Some how I missed @Gernot's comment. This answer is nothing more than an expanded version of what he wrote.]

I think that you have two problems.

1. A typo: `tabular==|l|r|` should be `tabular=|l|r|`.
2. There are missing arguments to the `\csvreader` command that are supposed to say how the table should be constructed.

From your question it is not entirely clear to me what `data.csv` looks like so I have used the file:

```
5.5
3806.0
601.0
26.8
150.0
2.0
75.0
21
```

Changing your MWE to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
  \csvreader[tabular=|l|r|,
  no head,
  table head=\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline]{data.csv}{}{\thecsvrow & \csvcoli}%
\end{document}
```

you now obtain the table:

[image]

Note that `\thecsvrow` gives the row number and, for a given row, `\csvcoli` gives the entry in column 1. There are also `\csvcolii`, `\csvcoliii` and so on. So the argument `{\thecsvrow & \csvcoli}` to `\csvreader` says that each of the table show start with the row index and then have the corresponding entry in column 1 of the data file.

Finally, I'd recommend reading the manual from the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package as it explains why you shouldn't use vertical rules in tables:)

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you ! I had read the manual but had not understood that the {} between the filename and the column choice was mandatory, nor had I understood that the column choice was mandatory. I thought csvreader would just take all columns if left unspecified (like csvautotabular). Again, big thanks ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without lines:

> \csvautobooktabular[table head=\toprule\csvlinetotablerow\]{data.csv}

[image: table layout]

This requires that you include in your header:

> \usepackage{booktabrule}

It's an easy solution because it doesn't need any more arguments. So, you can use it to read tables with a different number of columns – without having to re-specify them every time. It is straight from the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf), p. 39 / section 5.5.

However, if you want to change the style, for example add horizontal lines, I recommend @Andrew's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325363/134936).